# If someone has intercourse before Fajr and ejaculates before Fajr starts but doesn’t clean up in time is fast broken?

Tags: sawm, sex

If someone has intercourse before Fajr and ejaculates before Fajr starts but doesn’t clean up in time is fast broken?

As the title says I was wondering what the rule regarding this is since almost all questions answer before or after not when it becomes Fajr.